# How can I create remote repo and locate repo and do branch and diff?

Tags: git

I create my repo

```
git init my_remote_repo  
git clone my_remote_repo
git branch alex
```

fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.

```
git diff origin/master master
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

When you first create a repo, it's in a kind of weird, unusable state until the first commit.

```
git init my_remote_repo
```

Now you have a repo in the `./my_remote_repo` directory.  It's not a bare repo, which is atypical for a remote; and you're currently accessing it as a local repo (though you might be able to access it remotely as well, if you've set up a way for remote clients to reach it).

So far that's ok, if a little unusual.

But now if you look at the repo, you'd find that it has no commits.  It "knows" that by default it should be on a `master` branch, but that branch hasn't been "born" (it has no commits), and that will cause most commands to give errors.

```
cd my_remote_repo
```

If you're at a `git bash` prompt, it will indicate that you're on master.  Put some initial content in this directory, and then you can

```
git add .
git commit
```

In the text editor that pops up, enter a commit message, then save/exit; now you have a commit in your repo, and the errors you're seeing won't occur.

(If you want to start with no content in the repo, the above `commit` command would fail, but

```
git commit --allow-empty
```

will work in that case.)

At this point, you can clone the repo (though just saying `git clone my_remote_repo` from the repo's parent directory, as you've implied above, won't work because the default would be to put the clone at the same path as the original.)